# How to style multiple items on a single line with bullets between items on a line

Tags: css

I want bullets between items displayed on the same line and lines to contain several items as size permits.

For example, this list:

```
<ul>
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Orange Cake</li>
<li>Lemon</li>
<li>Juice</li>
<li>Chocolate Icing</li>
<li>Extremely Tasty Milk</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<ul>
```

should display like this:

```
Apples o Orange Cake o Lemon
   Juice o Chocolate Icing
 Extremely Tasty Milk o Tea
```

Comment: `li { display: inline; } li:before { content: "\2022 " }` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fq9s4/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is hiding the first marker in each line.

In general, I highly doubt there is a way in CSS to prevent that marker from being generated, because the list item target depends on the length of the previous line, and there are very few ways in CSS to target content based on layout (it seriously breaks the DOM-centric model of CSS), none of them applicable in this case.

The only recourse is to try to hide the marker through CSS.  Here is a way to do that, but it's ugly, as it requires fudging the parent of the `ul` (I am incorporating Sachin's answer, which is more concise than my initial approach with generated content).

Maybe someone can figure out a better approach to hide the marker.

http://jsfiddle.net/WtwzP/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/WtwzP/1/ (more verbose generated content option)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Apples</li>
        <!--...-->
        <li>Tea</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li { 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 25px;
} 

ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```